# ¿como podre realizar un consulta con dos tablas en join con mvc?

Tags: c#

estoy conflictivo  en como se realiza una consulta de dos tablas una producto y una tipo, se que se usa un join para justar tablas, abajo tengo un codigo de producto donde uso un linq para buscar y me funciona al momento de buscar un producto, pero no se como realizar uno con tipo donde tambien quiero que busque cuantos tipos hay registrados en la tabla producto. tengo un breve ejemplo de producto nomas, pero el tipo me complica,

mis base de datos son producto, tipo
problema no se como realizar un linq de buscar los tipos que hayan con esa palabra por ejemplo "herramientas", ver cuantos productos los tienen en clasificacion de tipo

aca esta mi VisitaController

```
public ActionResult Index(string proc)
    {
        //  var producto = db.producto.Include(p => p.tipo);
        // return View(producto.ToList());
        var buscar = from s in db.producto select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(proc))
        {
            buscar = buscar.Where(s => s.Descripcion.Contains(proc));
        }
        return View(buscar.ToList());
    }
```

aca esta mi vista html(vista)

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
<p>
    Buscar por Producto : @Html.TextBox("proc")
    <input type="submit" value="buscar" />
    Buscar por Tipo: @Html.TextBox("tipo")
    <input type="submit" value="query" />
</p>
}
```

Comment: Redacta bien para q se te pueda entender por favor

Comment: listo pa ya lo modifique

Comment: Sigo sin entender. Cuál es el problema? Cuál es el resultado esperado? Cuál es el resultado que obtienes

Comment: haya un buscador de tipo, cuantos productos estan ligados con la palabra por ejemplo"herramientas" cuantos productos estan en ese tipo "herramientas"

Comment: se lo tenga que implementar en el index de visitaController